# How do I Make a conditional String exist in an if statement? (answers to similar questions answers haven't worked)

Tags: conditional-statements, chatbot

I'm taking a programming class, and I started making a chat-bot like program.
I was trying to be able to teach it one thing (at least) if you said something like "I want to teach you".

Right now it only works if I use:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What word or phrase would you like to teach me to respond to?")
learn1Reply= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("So now, what do you want me to say when you type, '" + learn1 + "' in?");;
```

I don't know how to make it an if statement that would result in later typing:

```
else if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(learn1))
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, learn1Reply);
    }
```

I've read a bunch of answers on this site about creating conditional variables, but they haven't helped me.

I'm sure there's a much easier way to do this that I'm unaware of.

Comment: be careful about the punctuation in code and read the FAQ to find out how to use Markdown so it's formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing the data separate from the logic of the code. For example (I'm going to assume java because of your example, but I'm not really a java guy so forgive me if the generics stuff is incorrect):

```
HashMap responses = new HashMap<string, string>();
```

Then simply add to the map when responses are entered.

```
responses.put("something", "response text");
```

Or in your case:

```
responses.put(learn1, learn1Reply); // After you get the input
```

When you want to display the appropriate response, simply get it, rather than using some large if-else tree. (They get hard to read and maintain as they grow.)

So rather than

```
... else if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(learn1)){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, learn1Reply);
}
```

You can simply do the lookup itself.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, responses.get(learn1);
```